# print just list of causes to an exception

Tags: python, exception

Is there a way to get the list/chain of causes for an exception
so I can just print that list instead of having full trace backs
as `traceback.print_exception` does ?

The usecase is to not dump full stack trace on errors, but do list the
causes as often that is enough and more informative.

Something like:

```
MyError: Error occurred doing XYZ

homeassistant_cli.exceptions.HomeAssistantCliError: Error connecting to http://localhost:8123/api/discovery_info

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8123): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/discovery_info (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x106562e80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

Instead of the sometimes several screens of threadumps.

I tried traversing python `__cause__` chain but looking at `traceback.print_exception` there seem to be a lot of special cases to deal with.